# Dual boot Windows10 and Ubuntu problem (forcing to remove Windows)

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, windows-10

It asks me to erase and install but i want to install it alongside windows.
The image is taken while running live boot and installing Ubuntu.

[image]

Comment: have you booted in UEFI mode or BIOS/CSM/Legacy?

Comment: It is not seeing Windows which usually is because Windows has fast start up which is hibernation still on. Note Windows updates keep turning it back on. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions  Use Windows tools to shrink Windows and reboot into Windows so it can run chkdsk which it needs after any resize. Best to use Something Else install option. https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi & https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI Be sure to back up Windows before anything else.

Comment: Thanks for the help I had booted up in uefi mode, I tried in legacy mode and it worked.